# In a unit test, how to verify a function call within a Kotlin coroutine launched in the system under test?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, spring-integration, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Kotlin Spring Integration TCP/IP endpoint that launches a coroutine:

```
@MessageEndpoint
class MyTcpEndpoint(private val messageProcessor: MyMessageProcessor) {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundChannel")
    fun process(messageByteArray: ByteArray): String {
        val message = String(messageByteArray)
        GlobalScope.launch {
            // ... Create myDto object based on the message here
            messageProcessor.handleMessage(myDto)
        }
        log.trace("Sending 'OK' back to the calling camera")
        return "OK"
    }

}
```

This code works. It sends the "OK" back to the calling client without waiting for the end of the processing of the message. I'm new to Kotlin Coroutines and had to add it here to send the OK before the processing finishes. But now (after changing to a coroutine) my test doesn't work any longer because the test doesn't see the execution of the `messageProcessor.handleMessage(myDto)` in the coroutine or the test doesn't wait for its execution.

Here is my original test:

```
internal class MyTcpEndpointTest {

    @Test
    fun myTest() {
        // GIVEN
        val messageProcessor = mockk<MyMessageProcessor>(relaxed = true)
        val tcpEndpoint = MyTcpEndpoint(messageProcessor)

        val messageByteArray = myXmlString.toByteArray()

        // WHEN
        tcpEndpoint.process(messageByteArray)

        // THEN
        verify { messageProcessor.handleMessage(MyDto( ... )) }
    }
}
```

With this test I want to check that the `handleMessage()` function is called with the correct parameter.

After introducing the coroutine, the test fails because `handleMessage()` is not called before the test ends. How can I fix this?

I already tried to use runBlocking: `fun myTest() = runBlocking { ...` in conjunction with a change from `verify` to `coVerify`, but I get the same error.

Comment: Your problem is `GlobalScope.launch`. Use a proper dispatcher instead. Then you can return the `Job` returned from `launch`, and wait until it's finished. (you can do that with the `GlobalScope` job too, but you should still use a proper dispatcher).

Comment: The `@ServiceActivator` method also can be marked as `suspend`. Then `runBlocking` would work.